# How can I produce more than one file format per plot code in R?

Tags: image, r, plot

I use Github markdown to document my data analysis with R.  When I make a plot I use:

```
jpeg("file_name.jpg")
plot(...)
dev.off()
```

to save the plot as a jpeg that can then be embedded and displayed in the markdown document like this:

```
!(file_name.jpg)
```

However, I also need to make a `pdf` of the plot for the final publication.  Currently I write the entire plot code over again with `pdf("file_name.pdf")` but this results in a lot of basically duplicate code.

I have tried putting the `jpeg` and `pdf` calls in sequence but then only the bottom one gets produced.

Is there a way to make the `jpeg` and `pdf` file from the same code during only one run of the code?

Comment: If you're willing to use `ggplot`, you can save a plot and call it using `print`. `GG <- ggplot(...) ; print(GG)`

Comment: by the way, it's generally (although not always) better to use `png()` rather than `jpeg()` for bitmap versions of statistical graphics, unless you have photo-like images ...

Comment: @BenBolker thanks for the tip.  I was just using the `jpegs` for me to view in Github but the `png` images do look nicer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you can use `dev.copy`:

```
plot(cars)
dev.copy(jpeg, "cars.jpeg")
dev.off()
dev.copy(pdf, "cars.pdf")
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not to use `knitr`? for example:

````
```{r myplot,fig.width=7, fig.height=6,dev=c('png','pdf','jpeg')}
plot(cars)
```
````

This will create 3 versions/files of the same plot:

1. myplot.png
2. myplot.jpeg
3. myplot.pdf

Answer (score 3):

@agstudy's answer is clever.  The canonical answer, I think, is that if you have a lot of duplicate code you can make a little utility function and run it twice:

```
tmpplotfun <- function() { ... lots of plot code ... }
pdf(...)
tmpplotfun()
dev.off()
jpeg(...)
tmpplotfun()
dev.off()
```

You could even abstract this further:

```
plot_twice <- function(plotfun,...) {
   pdf(...)
   plotfun()
   dev.off()
   jpeg(...)
   plotfun()
   dev.off()
}
plot_twice(tmpplotfun)
```

... with a little more ingenuity you could replicate what `knitr` is already doing ...